# How does this differential conversion work / happen?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been given a couple of question sheets as well as reading material to help me with said questions. However, the reading material appears to miss out a step and I don't know how to make the final step to get the correct answer.
Basically, why does the equation below change the way it does?
$$
\mathbf a=(\ddot r-r\dot\theta^2)\mathbf e_r+(r\ddot\theta+2\dot r\dot\theta)\mathbf e_\theta=(\ddot r-r\dot\theta^2)\mathbf e_r+\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot\theta)\mathbf e_\theta
$$

In case it is unclear, it is the $(r\ddot\theta+2\dot r\dot\theta)\mathbf e_\theta=\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot\theta)\mathbf e_\theta$ part that I am not understanding.
The only rule I have been given is $\frac{d}{dt}(u^2)=2u\frac{du}{dt}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}{\dot r^2}=2\dot r\frac{d\dot r}{dt}=2\dot r\ddot r$, but I am failing to see the connection. Can anyone clear things up?

Answer (score 1):

Use the product rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(u·v)=\dot u·v+u·\dot v.
$$